# iPython/ Jupyter notebook clear only one line of output

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

How can I print the status of a Jupyter notebook on the previous line?  I think I'm looking for something like [clear_output()](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output), but for only a single line.

Sample code:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
print('This is important info!')
for i in range(100):
    print('Processing BIG data file {}'.format(i))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    if i == 50:
        print('Something bad happened on run {}.  This needs to be visible at the end!'.format(i))
print('Done.')
```

When this runs it gives the behavior of over-writing the previous status line, but both of the lines marked as important (with exclamation points and everything!) are lost.  When this is finished the display just says:

```
Done.
```

What it should say is:

```
This is important info!
Something bad happened on run 50.  This needs to be visible at the end!
Done.
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439629/ipython-notebook-print-above-last-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggests using clear_output() and then reprinting everything.  This seems impractical because the amount of data I really tend to display is big (lots of graphs, dataframes, ...).

Here's [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-print-over-the-current-line-in-a-command-line-application) links about clear_output().

Is there a way to make this work that doesn't involve reprinting everything?

Answer (score 8):

I got it woking using the update function of the display handle:

```
from IPython.display import display
from time import sleep

print('Test 1')
dh = display('Test2',display_id=True)
sleep(1)
dh.update('Test3')
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple escape sequence trick can do the job most of the time. `\n` and `\r` can do a lot if used properly.
`\r: (Carriage Return) (CR)`  returns the cursor to the beginning of the new line without moving to a new line.
`\n:(Line Feed) (LF)` moves the cursor to the next line.

```
import time
print('This is important info!')
for i in range(100):
    print("\r"+'Processing BIG data file {}'.format(i),end="")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if i == 50:
        print("\r"+'Something bad happened on run {}.  This needs to be visible at the end!'.format(i))
print("\r"+'Done.')
```

Comment: This works for me. Doesn't have any additional package overheads. Very lean.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```py
import IPython

IPython.display.display_javascript(r'''
    var el = document.querySelector('.output_text:last-of-type > pre');
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(\n.*$)/gm,""); ''', raw=True)
```

Comment: A bit of explaining would have helped, so I'll do it for you: you take the notebook's first output block (`pre`) and replace its HTML (our 2 lines of output) using a regexp that matches the second line of output to just keep the first one. You issue this command when necessary in code using the `display.display_javascript` method of the `IPython` class.