# Is it possible to dynamically update a cell using HTML for ipython Notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to replicate this [How can I print over the current line in a command line application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-print-over-the-current-line-in-a-command-line-application/21672188#21672188)

but using html so same example but

```
import sys
import time
from IPython.display import display,clear_output
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    HTML('<b> Hello  ' + str(i) + '</b>')
```

But it doesn't update. Is there a way to make it work?

In a Ipython Notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `HTML()` just creates an object of class `IPython.display.HTML`. Every object from this class, *when displayed by IPython* in a notebook, is shown as an html element that is included in the page. See 
[Custom Display](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Display%20Logic.ipynb) for details.

IPython default behavior is to display the last object computed in a cell, if it wasn't used or assigned, which means that a cell with the following code works as intended:

```
from IPython.display import display,HTML,clear_output
HTML('<b>Hello world</b>')
```

What you want here is to instruct IPython to display all your objects in sequence, not just the last one created. The `IPython.display.display()` function does the trick:

```
import sys
import time
from IPython.display import display,HTML,clear_output
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(HTML('<b> Hello  ' + str(i) + '</b>'))
```