# Pycharm overwrite output on console

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, openai-gym

I am experimenting with `gym` on `PyCharm`. This is my code:

```
import gym
from time import sleep

env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env

epochs = 0
penalties, reward = 0, 0

frames = []  # for animation

done = False

while not done:
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

        if reward == -10:
            penalties += 1

        env.render()
        sleep(.1)

        epochs += 1
```

Currently when I print it, it renders every state one after another on the PyCharm console. I want it to first clear the earlier output from the console and then print the next one. How do I make that happen?

Comment: You can't do it in an IDE console, you have to do so in a terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I overwrite/print over the current line in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-overwrite-print-over-the-current-line-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: @arzo I was hoping to do it in IDE. But looks like there is no way to do it in IDE

Comment: Yep console doesn’t ask the same in IDE