# python print function parameteres for print in one single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime

a = 100
b = 0 
while a > b:
     print(str(datetime.datetime.now()), end="\r")
     b += 1
     print(b)
```

> I don't know why this doesn't work, i've searched a lot and everyone does this like this but it doesn't work for me, im confused!
>
> What i want to achieve is to overwrite the print and print in the same line without making a ton of lines.

instead of this:

1

2

3

i wanted this:

1 and on the next print it would only appear 2 and next only 3 and etc..

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419488/2314391

Comment: i am not super familiar with python, but the difference between the two print lines really stands out for me ... why don't you examine the two print lined also ... use your intuition to discover a possible solution for your problem

Comment: So and could I do like : "print(f"{words}\r")

Comment: I tried everything and still not working

Answer (score 0):

[previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672188/13274830) but summarized here:

```
import sys 

while a > b: 
    print('\r')
    # delay for readability
    print('your statement')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this I believe! as per Python 3.x

Please read the document - [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Also, refer to this question - [how to overwrite stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)

```
import datetime

a = 100
b = 0 
while a > b:
     print(str(datetime.datetime.now()), end="\r")
     b += 1
     print(b, end = '\r')
```

OR

```
for x in range(10):
    print('{0}'.format(x), end = '\r')
print(end='\r')
```