# How do I make it so that I can change what has already been printed in python?

Tags: python, windows, terminal

Here is some example code:

```
def printAsGrid(listName,rowLength):
    gridStr=''
    for n in range(len(listName)):
        if n % rowLength == 0:
            gridStr += '\n'
            gridStr += listName[n] +''
        else:
            gridStr += listName[n]
        
    print(gridStr)

myList = []
for i in range(20):
    myList.append('a')

print(myList)

for i in range(0,20):
    myList[i] = "b"
    printAsGrid(myList,5)
```

I've looked here and I know about `\r` and the ANSI exit codes but it doesn't work for windows terminal (they did work for the ubuntu terminal).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\r` works in Windows Command Prompt (`cmd`). Please show a [mre] of what does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I overwrite/print over the current line in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-overwrite-print-over-the-current-line-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with clearing the entire terminal after each iteration, you could try using something like

```py
import os

def printAsGrid(listName, rowLength):
    gridStr = ''
    for n in range(len(listName)):
        if n % rowLength == 0:
            gridStr += '\n'
            gridStr += listName[n] + ''
        else:
            gridStr += listName[n]

    # use the appropriate system command to clear your terminal. 
    os.system('clear') 
    # the normal print statement
    print(gridStr)


myList = 20*['a']

for i in range(0, 20):
    myList[i] = "b"
    printAsGrid(myList, 5)
```

On a side note, you might want to look into list comprehension to make your `printAsGrid` function a little bit easier to read, such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354/21688300).