# Remote download large files in python

Tags: python, shell

I want to download large file which can be mp3s, video, etc so i know that we download files using `import urllib` or `requests` but will it work for big files 300mb, 500mb+ ... ?  but the file i want to download is behind a login members area and only members can download i have the username and password i'm one of the member of site and i can download the file manually by right click download file save as and download url look like `http://xxxcontentdeliverynetworkxx.com/filepath.mp4?a-long-query-string-with-unique-token-like:-f01e3b4be2ed6f8c846f652e03438370110f8da05`

I have searched and got the idea i need to set headers, manage sessions, store cookies i'm coming from php programming so still learning python i need to know how to do it in python and where to get started for doing this any code examples will highly appreciated

Regards

Comment: I think your shift key is broken, as are the keys for comma and period. Seriously, this lack of punctuation is a readability impairment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With requests, you need to pass the auth values as a tuple, like:

```
requets.get(...., auth=('myuser', 'mypass'))
```

Comment: that worked, any way to add the file download progress bar?

Comment: You need to pass the stream param to true, and iterate over the result updating the bar (explained in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644964/python-progress-bar-and-downloads)

Comment: That was awesome i got everything sorted and one last thing i was wondering if we can get the filename of remote file that we are about to download?