# Get data FROM progress bar

Tags: python, progress-bar

There is a considerable amount of data on how to make progress bars in python ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644964/python-progress-bar-and-downloads)). My question is the other way around; instead of providing data to the user, I want data from a progress bar.

I have a program (black box) which outputs its own progress in a progress bar form to stderr:

```
100% building index
12% creating mask
```

And the percentage is updated as it runs. I am calling this program using `subp = subprocess.Popen(cmd)`.

It seems that the program's output is not explicitly buffered until a certain task reaches 100%. Using subprocess.PIPEs I was able to catch the output when a task reaches 100% but not while it is still running. Is it possible to catch the progress percentage continuously?

Comment: You can check the stdout over intervals while running