# Requests + Tqdm to a variable

Tags: python, function, file, python-requests, tqdm

I got this function right here from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644964/python-progress-bar-and-downloads) (ctrl+ f for "There is an answer with requests and tqdm"):

```py
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
def download(url: str, fname: str):
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total = int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    with open(fname, 'wb') as file, tqdm(
        desc=fname,
        total=total,
        unit='b',
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            size = file.write(data)
            bar.update(size)
```

Basically it downloads a file and writes it to a file, and I wanted it to return a variable that rapresents the downloaded file, so I made this:

```py
def download(url: str, fname: str):
    import requests
    from tqdm import tqdm
    import os
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total = int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    with open(fname, 'wb') as file, tqdm(
        desc=fname,
        total=total,
        unit='b',
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            size = file.write(data)
            bar.update(size)
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        returned = f.read()
    os.remove(fname)
    return returned
```

Now it saves the file, reads it and saves it to a variable, deletes the file and returns the variable.
Is there a way I can save it directly to a variable?

Comment: Of course, instead of calling `file.write(data)`, you could do something else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just return a tqdm iterator, and do whatever you like with the chunks:

```
import requests
import tqdm
import io

def download(url: str):
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total = int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    with tqdm.tqdm(
        desc=url,
        total=total,
        unit='b',
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=65536):
            bar.update(len(chunk))
            yield chunk

bio = io.BytesIO()

for chunk in download('http://...'):
    # Do something with the chunk; this just stores it in memory.
    bio.write(chunk)

content = bio.getvalue()  # Get the contents of the BytesIO() as a bytes.
```

Of course you can then refactor this to

```
import requests
import tqdm
import io


def download_as_bytes_with_progress(url: str) -> bytes:
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total = int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    bio = io.BytesIO()
    with tqdm.tqdm(
        desc=url,
        total=total,
        unit='b',
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=65536):
            bar.update(len(chunk))
            bio.write(chunk)
    return bio.getvalue()
```